# Created BroadcastReceiver which displays application name and version number on install/ uninstall of any application?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Created BroadcastReceiver which displays application name and version number on install/ uninstall of any application. But i am getting package name through `intent.getData()`.  But when i am trying to find the name of that application using packagemanager it's throwing an exception in all the cases Install/ Uninstall/ Replaced. What could be the possible problem and how can this be fixed?

CODE:

```
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
    import android.widget.Toast;

public class ApplicationStatusNotification extends BroadcastReceiver {

    /**
     * This method receives message for any application status(Install/ Uninstall) and display details.
     */
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // Get application status(Install/ Uninstall)
        boolean applicationStatus = intent.getBooleanExtra(Intent.EXTRA_REPLACING, false);
        String toastMessage = null;

        // Check if the application is install or uninstall and display the message accordingly
        if(intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL")){
            // Application Install
            toastMessage = "PACKAGE_INSTALL: "+  intent.getData().toString() + getApplicationName(context, intent.getData().toString(), PackageManager.GET_UNINSTALLED_PACKAGES);
        }else if(intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED")){
            // Application Uninstall
            toastMessage = "PACKAGE_REMOVED: "+  intent.getData().toString() + getApplicationName(context, intent.getData().toString(), PackageManager.GET_UNINSTALLED_PACKAGES);
        }else if(intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED")){
            // Application Replaced
            toastMessage = "PACKAGE_REPLACED: "+  intent.getData().toString() + getApplicationName(context, intent.getData().toString(), PackageManager.GET_UNINSTALLED_PACKAGES);
        }

        //Display Toast Message
        if(toastMessage != null){
            Toast.makeText(context, toastMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method get application name name from application package name
     */
    private String getApplicationName(Context context, String data, int flag) {

        final PackageManager pckManager = context.getPackageManager();
        ApplicationInfo applicationInformation;
        try {
            applicationInformation = pckManager.getApplicationInfo(data, flag);
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            applicationInformation = null;
        }
        final String applicationName = (String) (applicationInformation != null ? pckManager.getApplicationLabel(applicationInformation) : "(unknown)");

        return applicationName;
    }
}
```

Comment: There's one thing you most likely wanted to change, instead of listening for Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_INSTALL, you're maybe looking for Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED. Based on documentation first one should have never been used and it's quite surprising if you've received such action.

Comment: Yes but still pckManager.getApplicationInfo(packageName, flag) is throwing NameNotFoundException exception.

Comment: Can you add in onReceive method Log.d("MyApp", "Receive intent: " + intent); and add logcat message?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I followed [this](http://www.xinotes.org/notes/note/1335/) example where BroadcastReceiver is introduced as follows;

```
<receiver android:name="PackageChangeReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED"/>
        <data android:scheme="package"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Now once PackageChangeReceiver.onReceive(..) is called, Intent.getData() Uri contains something around; `package:my.test.package` which is returned by Uri.toString(). For searching this ApplicationInfo using PackageManager you should extract package name only which can be retrieved by `Uri.getSchemeSpecificPart()` which should give you `my.test.package` only.

Also, based on quick testing, it seems very likely that after package removal there's no ApplicationInfo available anymore.

Comment: Thanks bro... It works when the application is installed but when application is uninstalled still i facing the same problem.